# Editing bst file to underline title

Tags: bibtex, line-breaking, natbib, text-decorations, custom-bib

I could not find an option in makebst that would make the titles of articles be underlined, however, using `emphasize` in an otherwise correct bst I was able to underline it. Unfortunately   this makes the resulting underlined text get outside the margins. My code is

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,letterpaper,spanish]{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[activeacute,spanish]{babel}
\addto\shorthandsspanish{\spanishdeactivate{~<>.}}
\decimalpoint %\spanishdecimal{.}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
asdasd \citep{chsh_inequality} asdasd \citep*{aspect_test_bell}
\bibliographystyle{fiuady3}
\bibliography{ejem_biblio}

\end{document}
```

and my bib file is

% This file was created with JabRef 2.5.
% Encoding: Cp1252

```
@ARTICLE{chsh_inequality,
   author = {{Clauser}, J.~F. and {Horne}, M.~A. and {Shimony}, A. and {Holt}, R.~A.
    },
    title = "{Proposed Experiment to Test Local Hidden-Variable Theories}",
  journal = {Physical Review Letters},
     year = 1969,
    month = oct,
   volume = 23,
   number = 15,
    pages = {880-884},
      doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.23.880},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1969PhRvL..23..880C},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

@ARTICLE{aspect_test_bell,
   author = {{Aspect}, A. and {Grangier}, P. and {Roger}, G.},
    title = "{Experimental Tests of Realistic Local Theories via Bell's Theorem}",
  journal = {Physical Review Letters},
 keywords = {Fluorescence, phosphorescence},
     year = 1981,
    month = aug,
   volume = 47,
   number = 15,
    pages = {460-463},
      doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.47.460},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1981PhRvL..47..460A},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

The bst file I generated with makebst is http://pastebin.com/ji5d4vrx. On line 527 replacing `{ title` with `{ emphasize title` makes the titles become underlined, but they come outside of the margins. like this[image]

How could I fix the margins? Also, how to add the missing spaces between the authors and the title and between the title and the year?

Comment: Underlining is a sure sign of bad typography; please, don't do it.

Comment: But I absolutely have to.

Comment: In this case look at what the `soul` package provides.

Comment: But that is meant for use in the body of the document, how can I make it work through a bst?

Comment: If I make the change you propose, I get that the author list is underlined.

Comment: yeah, sorry it was with `{ title emphasize` not `{ emphasize title`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to revise your `.bst` file. For instance, change lines 1574--1575 into

```
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname bbluline\endcsname\relax\let\bbluline\underline\fi"
```

and in your TeX file write

```
\usepackage{ulem}
\def\bbluline#1{\uline#1}
```

Also the definition of `\enquote` should be changed: lines 1572-1573 should be

```
  write$ newline$
  "\newcommand{\enquote}[1]{~`#1'\ }"
```

Moreover, line 197 must be changed as

```
    { "\bbluline{" swap$ * "}" * }
```

(that is, changing `\uline` into `\bbluline`).

Of course, line 527 should become

```
526 FUNCTION {format.title}
527 { title emphasize
528    "title" bibinfo.check
```

that is, removing also `add.blank`.

Comment: That will produce a similar result, the underlined text goes on until it reaches the margins.

Comment: @OscarLazo Not in my experiment. Actually the plain `\uline` from `ulem` would work if you didn't enclose the full title in the additional pair of braces.

Comment: Could you post your code? I'm pretty sure I did just what you suggested.

Comment: @OscarLazo Sorry, I forgot the change on line 197, where `\uline` should become `\bbluline`

Comment: I tried with just 

`\usepackage{ulem}
\def\bbluline#1{\uline#1}`

in the tex file and `"\enquote{ \uline" swap$ *` in line 531

Comment: @egreg I am struggling with the same issue. Only the journal name is need to be underlined. Bst file: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wDgxR3tqsp/ Bib file: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TMrKHzyxS4/ Could you help for the solution, please?

Comment: @volkan That's a completely new question

Comment: @egreg I open a new topic. I would appreciate if you could browse. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487895/underline-the-journal-name-in-bst-file Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

write into the preamble of your document

```
\usepackage{soul}
```

and change the title function in your bst file to

```
FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title add.blank
   "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "\enquote{\ul{" swap$ *
      non.stop
        { "}} " * }
        { "}} " * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

then it should work.

Comment: what is a typo? If I do what you suggest I get an error after pdflatex bibtex pdflatex:
`Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed`