# Underline the journal name in bst file

Tags: custom-bib

I am trying to do underline only the journal names.

[Bst file link](https://zerobin.net/?0ff7010830e1b8d4#oYSdjOt4LJSlp92rojqCeXR8JcRZ72cYgdqlg9DCE9o=)

[Bib file link](https://zerobin.net/?7d4901d45d506bcf#WtBThztW6VuiXbMbIPQHdDKEAouto9AUnzTfhwBz8mg=)

Is it possible with editing bst file?

My main.tex

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\citep{latex2e} \\
\citep{knuth} \\
\citep{frattini2013} \\
\citep{frattini20132yazar} \\
\cite{Ansin1994} \\
\citep{web}  \\

\bibliographystyle{KTUtez}
\bibliography{tez}

\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like it's necessary to have an Ubuntu One account (whatever that may be) in order to download the bst file and the bib file. Please provide a setup that does not require potential answer-writers to set up an Ubuntu One account first.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I updated.

Comment: Sure... I am writing a thesis. The format wants me to underline journal names. I am agree with you, it is really bad. But I must do it.